# Export complete database to a remote server including (Tables, Stored Procedures, Triggers)

Tags: sql-server

How do we "export" a complete Microsoft SQL server database from one server to a "remote" server (including all the "stored procedures" and "triggers").  The export facility provided in the management studio seem to only export the tables and nothing else.

EXTRA NOTE:

Many thanks guys for your kind and detailed response.  To be more specific I'm trying to upload a local database that I created along with my .NET application to my web hosting server which I have limited access to.  I can only connect to my database through SQL Management Studio and there is no cPanel or Plesk type configuration that would allow me to perform a backup/restore operation or anything fancy.  I did as Kin suggested and generated a script and ran it on the remote database.  The following is the list of errors generated which seem to be a permission issues.  Is there any way I could elevate the security of my user account to bypass these errors on my side.  OR are there any other way of performing this export?

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'CONTAINMENT'.
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'FILESTREAM'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME'.
```

Comment: If you have ability to take backup and restore database that will be quickest method. Or you have use method mentioned by @Kin below. But in any case, you will have to deal with logins and database users as they will not get exported by any of methods.

Answer (score 3):

*How do we "export" a complete Microsoft SQL server database from one server to a "remote" server (including all the "stored procedures" and "triggers").*

Right click database --> tasks --> Generate scripts

*The export facility provided in the management studio seem to only export the tables and nothing else.*

**Incorrect**. You can infact script the entire database including data as well (though I would not recommend scripting data -- as the script wont be able to run using SSMS or sqlcmd, etc).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thank Kin for your visual and thorough answer.  I have updated the question.  Please have a look and comment.

Comment: @Sam there are 2 types of errors you have encountered. Check the user permission and make sure it has alter database permission -- "User does not have permission to perform this action.ALTER DATABASE statement failed". Also, check the script as it has syntax errors near CONTAINMENT, FILESTREAM and TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME tables.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use SSMS's Generate Script option, there are a few things that feature is lacking.

E.g., Non-Clustered Indexes on the table, constraints, permissions that are specific to a table, etc.

I use Red Gate's SQL Compare to take care of all that.
For each table, it would include all "CREATE NON-CLUSTERED INDEX" commands and GRANT/ALTER permissions for them, etc.

You could create a Script Folder (or sync) in SQL Compare and totally rebuild the DB structure on the other side.

Comment: Thanks dng, but Red Gate seem to be a very pricy software which I can't afford at this stage.